# Crear tabla en PHP utilizando arrays y foreach

Tags: php, html, array, foreach

con html/php y utilizando **arrays** y la estructura **foreach** quiero sacar por pantalla tablas de multiplicar, de manera que se impriman en forma de tabla, cada columna equivaldría a la tabla 5, otra del 13 y otra del 11. Cada array sería de la forma:

```
$tablas=[
“primera”=>5,
“segunda”=>13,
“tercera”=>11
];
```

Este sería el tipo de tabla que busco:
[image: Este sería el tipo de salida por pantalla que busco]

Paso enlace de lo que tengo hasta ahora por si alguien me puede echar una mano:
https://github.com/Denis110389/RepositorioEntornoServidor/blob/master/multiplicar.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tablas de multiplicar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloPHP.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $tablas=[
                "primera"=>5,
                "segunda"=>13,
                "tercera"=>11
            ];
           
            echo "<table border= 1>";
            
            foreach($tablas as $clave=>$valor){
                
                //ESTE IF DA TITULO A LA TABLA DEL 5
                $i=0;
                if(($valor==5) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Primera Tabla</td>";
                }
                //ESTE IF DA TITULO A TABLA DEL 13
                $i=0;
                if(($valor==13) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Segunda Tabla</td>";
                }
                //ESTE IF DA TITULO A TABLA DEL 11
                $i=0;
                if(($valor==11) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Tercera Tabla</td>";
                }

                //FOR QUE CALCULA CADA OPERACION DE LAS TABLAS E IMPRIME
                for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$valor."x".$i."=" .($valor * $i)."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si te refieres a que no te quedan en columnas, pon la etiqueta tr fuera del foreach($tablas as $clave=>$valor) justo despueés de  echo "table border= 1"; y la de echo "/tr"; antes de echo "/table";

La etiqueta tr lo que hace es cambiar de fila en la tabla.

Añado el código por si te vale:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tablas de multiplicar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloPHP.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $tablas=[
            "primera"=>5,
            "segunda"=>13,
            "tercera"=>11
        ];
       
        echo "<table border= 1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        
        foreach($tablas as $clave=>$valor){
            
            //ESTE IF DA TITULO A LA TABLA DEL 5
            $i=0;
            
            //ESTE IF DA TITULO A TABLA DEL 13
            $i=0;
            
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<table border= 1>";
                echo "<tr>";
                //FOR QUE CALCULA CADA OPERACION DE LAS TABLAS E IMPRIME
                if(($valor==5) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Primera Tabla</td>";
                }
                if(($valor==13) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Segunda Tabla</td>";
                }
                //ESTE IF DA TITULO A TABLA DEL 11
                $i=0;
                if(($valor==11) && ($i==0)){
                    echo "<td>Tercera Tabla</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

                for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$valor."x".$i."=" .($valor * $i)."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
                
                echo "</table>";
                echo "</td>";
            

            
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Haciendo eso se me queda igual, el problema es que de la manera que lo tengo escrito se me construye todo en una misma columna, en lugar de 3 columnas (una para cada tabla de multiplicar).

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, crea tres columnas, cada una con las tablas de multiplicar que estás pasando en el array.